# Identifying characters in strings

Tags: c++, c, string

What is the shortest way to check if a string contains the character "-" or it contains only numbers?

*Edit:* And how would I do it in C without std::string?  Which one is better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::string` has a member function, `find`, which can be used to search for a character or substring.  It returns `std::string::npos` if the search character or substring is not found.

One straightforward way to test whether a string contains only digits is to use the `find_first_not_of` member function with the search list `"0123456789"`.  If it returns `std::string::npos`, the string contains only digits; if it returns any other value, there is some other, nondigit character in the string.

Answer (score 2):

To check if it contains any character for eg. `"-"` you can use the `strchr()` c library call.

As to checking if a string contains only numbers you most probably have to iterate through all characters and check if it is a digit using `isdigit()` c library call.

As for the C++ way take a look at James McNellis's answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
std::string myStr = "999-111-100";
if(myStr.find("-")!=std::string::npos)
{
    //string has a - in it
}
```

Comment: It returns `std::string::npos` which is `-1` (not 0).